# clear token cookie using react js after logout

Tags: reactjs

i am using react cookie for storing the tokens in the cokies..can any one tell me..how to clear cookies when used logout..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';


class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    }
    logout = (e) => {

        cookies.remove('Token');
        window.location.href = '/';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Dashboard">
                <div>Dashboard</div>
                <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withCookies(Dashboard);
```

Comment: how r u routing? are you using react-router?

Comment: window.location.href = '/';   i am using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for these thing... i have imported instanceOf from the prop-type...  and changing the name of the Cookies to cookies...its clearing cookies after using logout

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';


class Dashboard extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };

    logout = (e) => {
        const { cookies } = this.props;
        cookies.remove('Token');
        window.location.href = '/';
        // return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Dashboard" token={this.state.token} >
                <div>Dashboard</div>
                <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withCookies(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false:

```
logout = (e) => {

     cookies.remove('Token');
     window.location.href = '/';
     return false;
}
```

Comment: ('cookies' is not defined )     response is like this

Comment: You need to import `import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';` Also, most people use universial cookies or  js-cookie since its simpler to use.

Comment: thanks very much james for the help....i got the solution for that thing...in another way....ill post the anwser now